# Get x files from a directory (batch, windows)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory, cmd

I have a directory with thousans of files.

Is there any way to get just x files? (preferably for batch file usage)

BUT (and that's why it is not one of the same questions to whom I already found answers)

without having the "dir" command work through the whole directory content
OR using the "for" loop.

Though the "for" loop (i.e for %%a in (*.txt) do [something]) combined with a counter would work, it takes quite some time to do so. I can only assume that the "set" of files (i.e (*.txt)) in the "for" loop gets the whole content first and iterates over it.

If I could stop the "dir" command after x returned values, it would be fine but I couldn't figure a way to do this (is it even possible or did I just answer my question but lacking the knowledge to do the coding for it?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for` command says: *the reports of my misperformance were an exaggeration*... and `dir` replies: *mine too*.

Comment: 1.- Any method to get the directory contents will, at a low level, read the directory in very big chunks, probably the complete directory with just one disk access, or with no disk access at all, as it tends to be in the disk cache. 2.- Any method to return the directory contents have an implicit sorting that requires the OS to read the full directory.  To speed up the reading, you need to specify no sorting of the directory. If you find diferences in `dir` vs `for` are due probably to the previous caching of the contents.

Comment: @PA.-You bring up an interesting point. And it leads me to wonder, How is it that a command like FOR is able to see entries that are added or changed after it has begun iterating?

Comment: @dbenham ... you're right, it's interesting. Maybe it detects the change in the directory contents and re-reads it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken about the FOR loop. It is extremely fast as long as you do not use the /R option. (I've tested on XP, Vista and Windows 7)

I created a test directory containing 20,000 files and ran the following script - it printed out the 1st 10 files and finished in the blink of an eye:

```
@echo off
set n=0
for %%F in (*) do (
  echo %%F
  set /a "n+=1, 1/(10-n)" 2>nul || goto :break
)
:break
```

I detect when I've reached 10 files by intentionally dividing by 0 to generate an error. I could have used delayed expansion and tested the value of my counter, but `%%F` would not print properly if the file name contains a `!` character and delayed expansion is enabled.

So contrary to your belief, a simple FOR does *not* collect all the values before iterating the loop.

You may have gotten confused with the FOR /F variant: `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *') do ...`. In this case the DIR command is executed in its own shell, and the entire result set *is* obtained before any FOR iterations.

One thing to be aware of with the FOR solution - the FOR /R option seems to have the potential to slow things down. I modified the script above to use the /R option and then ran it on my `C:\` root. It very quickly printed the first 10 files it found, but then appeared to hang for a long time, and then finally finished. I don't know how to prove this, but I think the FOR loop was wasting its time iterating all of the directories on my `C:` drive, even though it wasn't doing anything with them.

***EDIT***

I just read PA.'s comment to the original question. He has an excellent point - at some level both FOR and DIR must be reading the entire directory in order to perform the implicit sort operation to return the files in the correct order. However, he also points out this is done at a very low level. My point is that the FOR command does not need to wait for all the values to be returned before it begins iterating (or breaks out of the loop for that matter).

***EDIT 2***
The FOR /F behavior can be a blessing and a curse. For this application it is a curse. But sometimes you are changing the contents of the directory while you are processing it. The FOR /F variant protects you from seeing any changes that take place after the command has started. The simple FOR command can sometimes see changes to the directory contents after it has begun iterating.

The FOR command buffers the iterations in chunks - it will iterate all files it has in the buffer, but when the buffer is empty and it goes back to the OS to get the next chunk, it can then see changes that have occurred to the directory. Here is a test script that demonstrates the behavior:

```
@echo off
md myTemp
for /l %%N in (1001 1 6000) do echo a>myTemp\%%N.txt
for /f %%N in ('dir /b myTemp\* ^| find /c /v ""') do Echo Starting with %%N files
set cnt=0
(
  for %%F in (myTemp\*) do (
    echo %%F
    del /q myTemp\* 2>nul
    set /a cnt+=1
  )
)> test_for.out
echo Only %cnt% files were listed by FOR
echo(

for /l %%N in (1001 1 6000) do echo a>myTemp\%%N.txt
for /f %%N in ('dir /b myTemp\* ^| find /c /v ""') do Echo Starting with %%N files
set cnt=0
(
  for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d myTemp\*') do (
    echo %%F
    del /q myTemp\* 2>nul
    set /a cnt+=1
  )
)> test_for_f.out
echo All %cnt% files were listed by FOR /F

rd myTemp
```

And here are the results:

```
Starting with 5000 files
Only 743 files were listed by FOR

Starting with 5000 files
All 5000 files were listed by FOR /F
```

Both loops start with 5000 files and delete all files after the 1st iteration. The FOR /F still processes all 5000 file names that were in the directory when it started. The FOR only processes 743 file names that fit in the buffer.

Note: I obtained the above results on Windows 7. I also tested on Vista and XP, where the results were identical except both of those only listed 35 files in the FOR loop instead of 743.

Comment: @PA. - thanks, but I'm going to have to change it. I tried to reproduce the FOR command seeing changes that occur mid stream, but I failed. I know it's an issue, but it seems to be more complicated than I thought. I also remember seeing a post dealing with the issue, but I can't find it... Aaargh.

Comment: oh, I just took your word for granted. :) I eagerly wait for your final explanation.

Comment: @PA. - I updated my answer with results of XP testing. All modern versions of Windows seem to behave the same. Just the size of the buffer seems to vary.

Comment: @dbenham - Thank you for this detailed answer. :) I didn't considered the FOR /F variant using the "dir" to get the desired set of files, exactly because of the "dir" usage. But, because of your good explanation I realized that I missed to state the following Info, which would turn my question in a whole other topic (I think):
The directory were the files are in, is not on my local machine, but on a NAS. So the FOR command is waiting for result from the NAS controler to work with. That's why I thought FOR does quite the same as DIR.
So I wonder how could I speed up things(if its even possible)

Comment: ...which surely depends on the NAS manufacturer (I suppose)
and I have to get some Unix/Linux knowledge. ^.^